# WPF : Bound IsEnabled MenuItem with ObservableCollection<T> Items.Any()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` in a class and i want to bind the `IsEnabled` property of a `MenuItem` Element with `ObservableCollection<T>`

```
Items.Any()
```

XAML =>

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MyMenu" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ????}" 
        Header="MENU">
</MenuItem>
```

C# =>

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Current = new MyClass();

    public ObservableCollection<Object> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Object>();

}
```

Comment: Any() is an extension method and as far as I know, you can only bind to properties. You'll need a property that returns Items.Any() and bind to that

Comment: You will need to create a value converter and pass in the collection. In the converter you can check if the collection has any item and return true or false accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

#### Idiomatic Solution: Commands

The idiomatic way to do this would be to bind your menu item to a command and have the command's `CanExecute` handler check whether your `Items` collection is empty.  The `MenuItem` will automatically be disabled if `CanExecute` returns `false`.

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Items { get; }

    public DelegateCommand MenuItemCommand { get; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        MenuItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            () => { /* Do Something */ },
            () => Items.Count > 0);

        Items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => MenuItemCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As per the MVVM pattern, you should set the `DataContext` of your screen (e.g., your `UserControl`, `Page`, or `Window`) to an instance of the view model.

To hook up your menu item to the command, modify your Xaml as follows:

```xml
<MenuItem Command="{Binding MenuItemCommand}"
          Header="MENU" />
```

There are countless examples of `DelegateCommand` implementations out there (sometimes called `RelayCommand`), but I'll include one here for completeness:

```cs
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public virtual bool CanExecute() => _canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true;

    public virtual void Execute() => _execute();

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.Execute();
    }
}
```

---

#### Alternate Solution: Binding `IsEnabled`

If you insist on not using commands, you could do the following:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Items { get; }

    public bool HasItems => Items.Count > 0;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        Items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasItems));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And update your Xaml as follows:

```xml
<MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems}"
          Header="MENU" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but the purpose is to NOT use the CommandPattern and bind it directly

Comment: Why?  You _should_ be using the command pattern for any 'invocable' control (buttons, menus, etc.).  Regardless, I updated my answer to include a command-free version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Style` and and bind to the `Count` property directly:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MyMenu" Header="MENU">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

The `ObservableCollection<T>` raises a change notification each time the `Count` property changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to `ObservableCollection<T>.Count` property and create a value converter which converts 0 to false and non-zero to true:

```
public class HasItemsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as int?) > 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then add your converter to resources and use in binding:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MyMenu" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource HasItemsConverter}}" 
        Header="MENU">
</MenuItem>
```